# setDestinationInExternalPublicDir and getExternalStorageDirectory not equal

Tags: android, android-download-manager, download-manager

In my app, I want download a zip file and unzip it.

In `DownloadManager` request I use this:

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/SingingStudio", "file.zip");
```

This is write file in external storage.

And when I want to access file:

```
String szip = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"SingingStudio"+File.separator+"file.zip";
```

This is get file from internal storage. And `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/")` too.

So I can not find the file .

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the documentation for `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), the first parameter is "the directory type to pass to [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String))". That method, in turn, has a limited set of values it accepts, and `"/SingingStudio"` is not one of them.

Comment: but setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/SingingStudio"...) is download file to external storage and i can see that

Comment: @user2563494: There is no guarantee that this will work on every device, and even if it does, there is no documented behavior for where `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` will download the file when you do not follow the documented options. Use `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` properly, then [use `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) to get the location where the file was downloaded.

Comment: i use getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/SingingStudio") but this is return internal storege too

Comment: so how can i download file to my dir by downloadManager if my code is wrong

Comment: @user2563494: Start by reading [the documentation for `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)). Then, use one of the documented valid values for the parameter to that method, such as `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`. Then, use that same value in your `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()` call.

Comment: tanks CommonsWare . but i want to download file to my folder

Comment: @user2563494: Then [use `setDestinationUri()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setDestinationUri%28android.net.Uri%29), where you use `Uri.fromFile()` to point to the `File` on external storage where you want the data to be downloaded. Or, write your own download code, avoiding `DownloadManager`.